# Rest API to check if folder exist inside a folder in document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I have a custom page to upload file to document library. For example, if there are 10 person, so inside root folder, I have 10 folder for each person, Named as per the ID of the person. So while uploading, there is a textbox where I enter the ID of that person.

Now when I click on upload button, I need to check if the folder for that person exist in root folder. If it exist, I need to upload it there.

there are many root folders, so I need to check it in all those folders for the folder of that person exist.

```
function getFolderToUpload()
{

$.ajax({
async: false,
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('EmployeeDocumentList')/folders?$select=Name",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
         $(data.d.results).each(function(){          {
             if(this.Name!="Forms")
             {
             CheckFolderExist();             
             }
             }
    });
},
        error: function (data) {
            alert("error checking folder exist");
        }
    });
}
```

By the code above, i get all the root folders, Now I need to check if a folder named `test` exist in any of those folders. So I wanted to ask if there is any lambda expression kind of code that I can write to search this test folder in all those folders.

Answer (score 3):

This query will let you know if the folder exists or not:

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<FolderName>/<NestedFolderName>')/Exists
```

The endpoint will return the 'Exists' property with a boolean value. Hope that helps!

Comment: This is the best answer to check if the folder exists inside a document library or not. Thanks for sharing !!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the full path to get the folder, i.e. `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('EmployeeDocumentList/folder/test')` instead of just grabbing the root and looping through. If you don't know where the folder is you could use a CAML query or even search to find it and then get it's URL.

Answer (score 0):

/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('basepath/folderName')/ListItemAllFields

...if the above returns record, folder exists, otherwise it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

that one worked for me

```
 let path = "the folder path";
    let url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+`/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('${path}')/exists`;
    $.ajax({
      url,
      method: "GET",
      headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.d.Exists) {
          console.log("Folder exists");
        } else {
          console.log("Folder does not exist");
        }
      },
      error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    })
```